# Serial Programming: Sender and Receiver

Tags: c, serial-port, xbee, termios

So I am using two Xbee ZB (S2B) in a project to transmit data from one to another. It is a 8 data bit, no parity, 1 stop bit system (8N1).

I have two questions.

**1.** *Since I am interfacing with an RS232 (DB9 connector) interface to USB adapter on my laptop, at a baud rate of B230400 would system calls to **fwrite/fread/fopen/fclose** be better to use than **write/read/open/close**?* (I assume fread() will not work properly since it doesn't have a baud rate configurations as far as I know.)

**2.** I having one computer running one program (the transmitter program), and another program (the receiver program). Both programs need to be able to read and write as I would like to be able to know from the transmitting and receiving side different sets of information.

Like the receiving side (if I see the letter Q, stop, and close the port) or the transmitting side (wait for the reading side to send the letter G to start writing and close when done writing).

Using some of the code from (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html) under non-canonical input processing, I tried to setup a basic template for writing and reading from the USB port from either side. My question is:

*If and does there need to be different configuration settings (c_cflag, c_iflag, c_oflag, c_lflag) to the termios struct (newtio) for the transmitting and receiving programs?*

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int open_port(char *path, int modes)
{
    int fd; // File descriptor for port

    fd = open(path, modes); // Open the path
    if(fd == -1) return -1; // Could not be opened

    printf("Port %s opened successfully.\n", path);
    return fd; // Return fd
}

int setBaud(struct termios *termios_p, int baud)
{
    int ires = 0; int ores = 0;
    switch(baud)
    {
        0:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B0);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B0);
            break;
        50:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B50);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B50);
            break;
        75:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B75);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B75);
            break;
        110:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B110);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B110);
            break;
        134:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B134);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B134);
            break;
        150:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B150);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B150);
            break;
        200:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B200);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B200);
            break;
        300:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B300);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B300);
            break;
        600:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B600);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B600);
            break;
        1200:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B1200);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B1200);
            break;
        1800:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B1800);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B1800);
            break;
        2400:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B2400);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B2400);
            break;
        4800:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B4800);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B4800);
            break;
        9600:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B9600);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B9600);
            break;
        19200:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B19200);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B19200);
            break;
        38400:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B38400);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B38400);
            break;
        57600:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B57600);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B57600);
            break;
        115200:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B115200);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B115200);
            break;
        230400:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B230400);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B230400);
            break;
        default:
            ires = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B9600);
            ores = cfsetispeed(&termios_p, B9600);
            break;
    }

    if(ires == -1 | ores == -1) return -1; // ISpeed or OSpeed could not be set
    else { printf("Baud set successfully to %d\n", baud); return 0; }
}

char* readIt(int fd)
{
    char buf;
    char *tmp;
    tmp = calloc(2, sizeof(char);

    if( read(fd, buf, 1) == 1 ) { tmp[0] = buf; tmp[1] = 0; } // Return char in tmp[0]
    else { tmp[0] = 0x45; tmp[1] = 0x52; } // Return ER in char meaning error
    return tmp;
}

int writeIt(int fd, char *str, int bytes)
{
    if( write(fd, str, bytes) == bytes ) return 0; // Write success
    else return -1; // Failed write
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int usb;
    volatile int STOP = 0;

    if(argc == 1) { printf("Must enter usb port path.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } // No second argument
    else if (argc > 1) { usb = open_port(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); }

    struct termios oldterm, newterm;

    tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio); // Save old terminal settings

    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio)); // Clear out struct
    if( setBaud(&newtio, 230400) != 0 ) { printf("Baud could not be set\n"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); } // Set up baud rate

    newtio.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL; // 8 data bits, enable receiver, local line 
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~PARENB | ~CSTOPB; // No parity, one stop bit 
    newtio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Disable software flow control
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // No timeout clock for read
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; // Wait for one character before reading another

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH); 
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio); // Set fd with new settings immediately

    /* Do writing or reading from port in here - readIt or writeIt*/

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio); // Set fd with old settings immediately
    close(fd); // Close fd

    return 0;
}
```

If possible, I'm looking for the most optimal write and read rates without data corruption handling at this point. By optimal, I'm talking about the best settings for the configuration flags for the termios struct.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"I'm looking for the most optimal write and read rates without data corruption handling"* -- Once the data hits the receiver, the only possibility of data loss is receiver or buffer overrun.  Your slow method of reading only one byte at a time could result in a buffer overrun.  It's definitely an inefficient use of a **read()** syscall.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point one, it's easy to get a `FILE*` from a file-descriptor using [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html). However, you have to remember that a `FILE*` by default is buffered, so what you write may not be sent immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [ANSI C Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) for communicating with XBee modules.  The `xbee_serial_posix.c` file includes a full serial interface, and higher layers in the driver provide parsing and dispatching of API frames.  Lots of sample programs as well.

You can either use the library directly, or reference the serial layer for writing your own termios serial code.

It's primarily designed for using XBee modules in "API mode" (`ATAP=1`), but there are also some pieces for "AT mode" (like the `xbee_term` sample).